# Create a view over navigationView, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, user-interface, view, swiftui, z-index

I'm creating a view embedded in a ZStack, something like this:

```
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        
    content
        
        if self.show {
                                
                VStack {
                    
                    HStack {
```

This is a viewModifier so I call this in my main view with for example: `.showView()`.

But what happened is that if I have a NavigationView, this view is only showing below the navigationView. (I have a navigationViewTitle that is over my view).

How can I solve this problem? I was thinking about some zIndex but it is not working. I thought also about some better placement of this .showView(), but nothing to do.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Desired behavior: View over navigationView (With zstack). Problem or error: NavigationView is over my ZStack. Code is quiete straightforward since it is a generic View embedded in a ZStack. I cant see your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach (it can be added animations/transitions, but it is out of topic). Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct ShowViewModifier<Cover: View>: ViewModifier {
    let show: Bool
    let cover: () -> Cover

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            content
            if self.show {
                cover()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Link", destination: Button("Details")
                    { self.isPresented.toggle() })
                Text("Some content")
                    .navigationBarTitle("Demo")
                Button("Toggle") { self.isPresented.toggle() }
            }
        }
        .modifier(ShowViewModifier(show: isPresented) {
            Rectangle().fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 200)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: So the main point here is that I should call the modifier in my NavigationView only, is that right?

So If I have a view that is not just "Button("details")" I should use a Binding in my children, is it correct?

Comment: `NavigationView only, is that right?` - yes. `should use a Binding in my children` - yes or via view model (environment object, etc.)