# Draw a view over the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm working on a bottom sheet that can be invoked from any other screen. The bottom sheet will be displayed on top of a half-opaque overlay and I would like the overlay to render full screen over any other view including the navigation bar and the tab bar.

However, I can't seem to be able to figure out how to get the content of the navigation bar to be behind the overlay. Here is what a demo of my current implementation looks like. As you can see, it's possible to interact with the content of the navigation bar even though it is visually displayed behind the overlay.

| Half Screen | Full Screen | Back button is still active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

And here is the simplified code of my current implementation:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainNavigationView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      NavigationLink(destination: AnoterView()) {
        Text("Navigate to the next screen")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct AnoterView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color(uiColor: .red)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .navigationTitle("Test")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

      ViewWithOverlay()
    }
  }
}

struct ViewWithOverlay: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {

      // I'd like this overlay to be rendered over the navigation bar
      Color(uiColor: .blue)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

      Color(uiColor: .green)
    }
  }
}
```

And the outcome:
[image]

As you can see, while the blue color, which represent my overlay, is drawn over the red color, the title and the back button are still displayed on top of the blue color.

I understand why this is happening, but I cannot think of any workaround in SwiftUI to fix this that can be invoked from any view.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the output you are looking for? You are setting the title in the ViewWithOverlay and that is why it appears.

Comment: Good callout @azamsharp, I've updated the code to make it more apparent what I'm trying to achieve. In practice, the overlay will only be displayed when the bottom sheet is on the screen and hidden by default.

Comment: Why don’t you use a sheet ? It displays over the navigation bar.

Comment: Unfortunately, sheet is full screen, so I won't be able to achieve my first screenshot with it.

Comment: @AllanSpreys Were you able to find a solution to it?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is to put the NavigationView inside a ZStack. This way it will be in a lower layer hidden by the layer above. Here is the code that completely hides the NavigationBar on the tap of the button.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                Text("Hello World")
                    .navigationTitle("Welcome")
            }
            
            VStack {
                
            }.frame(maxWidth: isPresented ? .infinity: 0, maxHeight: isPresented ? .infinity: 0)
                .background(.green)
            
            Button("Animate") {
                withAnimation {
                    isPresented.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @azamsharp. This is a good answer. The overlay is half-opaque, so the content behind it is still displayed. It looks a bit odd when the navigation bar disappears as soon as the overlay is displayed. I added a few screenshots from my current implementation.

Comment: Updated the code. Now it hides the NavigationBar.

Comment: Thank you @azamsharp, I believe it's a very similar answer to Asperi. It works well when the navigation view and the other view are right next to each other. But it's a bit hard to achieve when one of the screens is very deep down.

Comment: It just needs to be in the right order inside the ZStack.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overlay everything then it should be on root, including over `NavigationView` as well, ie.

```
ZStack {
  NavigationView {
    Color(uiColor: .red).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  }

  ViewWithOverlay()  // << here !!
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

Comment: Thank you @Asperi, this is a good answer. However, the problem is that the bottom sheet can be hidden pretty far from the navigation view. Imagine an app which has 7 screen before a screen with the bottom sheet. Drawing the view in the first screen to display the content from the 7th screen is not very efficient. I've updated my example with an extra view to make this challenge a little more apparent.

Comment: A view appearance/disappearance (and actually behavior) is managed by some view model in SwiftUI concept, so it does not matter where it is relative to NavigationView or any other view (and really must not be). So we construct layout as it should be, but conditions to show it should be somewhere else (state object, environment object, etc.). See for example this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63632033/12299030.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in a complex app example, each screen is likely to have its own view model. In my example, `MainNavigationView` is likely to have `MainNavigationViewModel`, and `AnotherView` is likely to have `AnotherViewModel`. So I'd like to change the change in `AnotherViewModel` to influence the appearance of the navigation bar without creating coupling between `AnotherViewModel` and `MainNavigationViewModel`.